# XAML or C# Code behind - what is processed first at compile time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm building on WPF. Now a problem i run into repeatedly is that it's unclear to me which part gets compiled/evaluated first: XAML or the C# CodeBehind. I'm unable to figure it out and due to that my code is 'bloated' regarding fail-safes of declaring and assigning things.

I've found old answers regarding that for Silverlight but the XAML specification says any implementation is entirely framework dependent - and i've found no proper explanation for WPF.

Can someone clear that up? Thanks!

Comment: XAML (Code "behind" is "behind" for a reason) - but the question is actually rather pointless. What's the real "problem"?

Comment: XAML is a markup language. Actually, WPF translates/parses XAML code in the famous ElementName.g.i.cs file (not visible in Visual Studio, but accesible by InitializeComponent method, just like winforms partial class with InitializeComponent method!). Then the first file is ElementName.g.i.cs calling a parser of xaml text, and after your ElementName.cs file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XAML doesn't compile at all.
The XAML designer automatically creates the "*.g.i.cs" file as you edit the XAML.
You can go to the code of this file like this:

- Go to the window constructor;
- Move the keyboard cursor to `InitializeComponent`;
- Press F12.

This file contains the code for the partial class.
Question: Which of the partial class files will compile? - not entirely correct.
Think of it this way: Before compilation, all the files of the partial class are merged (virtually) into one file. The compiler treats them as a whole.

The order in which members are declared in a class rarely matters, so the order in which the files are merged does not matter either.
The only place where it can matter is in the initialization of static members (in fact, only fields) that refer to each other.
If there is such a thing in your code, then the corresponding members need to be written sequentially in one file or explicitly set the order of their initialization in the static constructor.

Most likely you are interested in a slightly different question: In what order is the code generated by XAML and CodeBehind executed?
If you look at the Sharpe file that was generated from XAML, you will see that it consists of declaring fields and initializing them in the `InitializeComponent()` method.

The call to the `InitializeComponent()` method occurs in the Window constructor.
Before calling it, the fields are null.
During the call, the full execution of the code specified in the XAML occurs.
Once called, you can safely refer to any elements defined in XAML.